# creating my own file type and making it run another file?

Tags: java, batch-file, command-prompt

I'm currently writing my own programming language for my senior project and using java to compile it. (in a sense where it reads through a text file and pulls out keywords and phrases and acts on them how i define). i would like to be able to have my text file be of type ".SeniorProject" for example, and then double click it and then it direct to the actual java program that reads it and acts upon on, also i would like if it would take and give input/output through command prompt instead of eclipse which i'm currently using. could someone direct me to a guide to set this up or explain it if possible. i will be using a windows device for this, not linux so i know that makes it more complicated for me wanting to give and receive input from the command prompt.

Comment: Have a look at `help ftype` in a cmd window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to run the program outside of eclipe, you can compile it into a `.jar` file (Java executable). In eclipse, you can do this by going to `file -> export -> JAR file`. Afterwards, you can simply type `java <yourfilename>.jar` in the command prompt and use the program like this.

Associating the file extension with your jar is a little bit trickier, in theory you can associate any file extension to any executable, but only *windows* executables. 
You could maybe create a `.bat` file that simply starts your jar on the jvm or use an exe wrapper like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to create an exe form your jar file.

Comment: thanks this helps a lot, i think that pretty much sums up what i was asking for :)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Gumbo's answer, you can make a .bat file that runs

```
java javaprog.jar %*
```

or

```
java <any other args you want go here> JavaProg %*
```

If you then run `thisbatfile.bat c:\my.seniorProject` then your Java program will run and its Main method will have access to "c:\my.seniorProject" through its arguments variable.

To make it easier to run these, you can associate that .bat file with ".seniorProject" files.
You can associate your new batch file with .seniorProject files one of two ways:

1. (easy, manual) Double-click on a file that has the ".seniorProject" extension. That will bring up a dialog that will let you choose your batch file as the preferred program used to open ".seniorProject" files.
2. (harder, but you can script it and you can specify separate 'edit' and 'run' options that will display in the right-click menu) Use `assoc` to make a new file type alias and then use `ftype` to associate the 'open' action of that alias with your batch file.

Once the association is done, you can just double-click a .seniorProject file to run it.